# How do I stop Excel from formatting dates when copying in a sheet from another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, csv, date

I have written a macro into my Workbook, that opens a specified .csv file and copies the content into a new sheet in my original Workbook. One of the columns in the .csv contains dates in non-American format and Excel reads some of these as American and converts them (e.g. 12 Feb 2020[12/02/2020 non-American] is read as 2 Dec 2020 [12/02/2020 American].

Most dates are after the 12th day and thus cannot be converted to an American format and these are read as text. The rest are stored as a date-integer.

How do I stop this behaviour programatically?

The Workbook will be used by multiple users on various machines, so changing Windows date defaults is not a solution.

Thanks!

edits:
The source sheet is generated by another system and files are archived in a network location with column B data in "dd/mm/yyyy" format.

```
Dim Source_Sheet As Worksheet
Set Source_Sheet = Workbooks("example").Worksheets("example")

Dim Target_Sheet As Worksheet
Set Target_Sheet = Workbooks("example2").Worksheets("example2")

Source_Sheet.Copy After:=Target_Sheet
```

I think the change in format happens during the copy of the sheet.

The csv is opened as:

```
Workbooks.Open ("file")
```

Comment: Please show your code ([edit] your question to include it). We can't tell what you did wrong if we cannot see it. Please also include sample data that shows/represents all cases (wrong and correct) and please tell if your textdate format in the CSV is `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Comment: Note that if you just open a CSV file like `Workbooks.Open ("file")` you let Excel *guess* which format each column data is (and Excel is not pretty good in guessing sometimes). That is probably why Excel guesses your date format wrong. See [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3165-how-to-import-csv-file-into-worksheet.html) how to import CSV data more reliable and choose the correct format for the columns. If you don't know how to code that in VBA use the Macro Recorder for a first idea.

Answer (score 1):

If the format in which your date data is displayed is "dd/mm/yyyy", the code below will apply.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim vR()
    Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
    Dim Source_Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim Target_Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long, n As Long
    Dim s As String, vS As Variant

    Set Source_Sheet = Workbooks("example.xlsx").Worksheets("example")
    Set Target_Sheet = Workbooks("example2.xlsx").Worksheets("example2")

    Source_Sheet.Copy After:=Target_Sheet
    Set Ws = Target_Sheet.Next

    With Source_Sheet
        Set rngDB = .Range("b1", .Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    r = rngDB.Rows.Count
    ReDim vR(1 To r, 1 To 1)
    For Each rng In rngDB
        n = n + 1
        s = rng.Text
        If InStr(s, "/") Then
            vS = Split(s, "/")
            vR(n, 1) = DateSerial(vS(2), vS(1), vS(0))
        Else
            vR(n, 1) = s
        End If
    Next rng

   With Ws.Range("b1").Resize(r)
        .Value = vR
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This will work if the the data from CSV was imported as **text/string**. But worth to mantion that during the CSV import Excel might already try to convert the strings into dates (Excel tries to guess in default mode) and so the dates might already be messed up during the import. So it is absolutely necessary to have an eye on the import, so it is either imorted as text (without Excel guessing) and then use your code above or as correct date (by specifying the correct format in the import dialog) and set the desired numberformat then.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, My guess is that the original data of the op is an Excel file, which is expressed as a date in different countries. There is a limitation that the op's description of the contents of the original file is not clear.

Comment: Well the OP's first sentence says the source is a csv: *"I have written a macro into my Workbook, that opens a specified .csv file"* and in his last sentece he says *"The csv is opened as: `Workbooks.Open ("file")`"* so there is indeed the danger of Excel guessing and trying to convert the dates in default mode. Since dates in CSV are always strings there is no reliabilty of guessing them right. Best way would be using ISO dates: http://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: @PEH sorry when you say "by specifying the correct format in the import dialog", how does that look like in VBA (i.e. telling it to import something as text as opposed to date)? i have a very similar problem to the OP and the field in question is definitely being treated as a date field at import so before i even start any date functions manipulation, the field is wrong to begin with....

Comment: OK i have actually found this which works by setting the local region as True when loading the workbook: Workbooks.Open(Filepath, Local:=True)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the values are in same format i.e `dd/mm/yyyy`.

While copying into excel use equal to operator `="12/02/2020"`. This will force excel to save data as text without changing the date format.

After copying then you can convert text to date with format `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Comment: *"without changing the date format"* that is not true. Excel cannot tell which date format this string is `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` and therefore it "guesses". This might easily end up wrong, depending on the format that your operating system uses. Since OP says this is used by various machines they may have various formats set in the OS. Rule No. 1 should be: Never let Excel guess which date format a string is (or you might end up in a mess soon).

Comment: I didn't mention how excel change the date format. what I meant: it will not change the format. Solution i gave will treat the input value as text.

Comment: Well dates as strings are pretty useless to Excel, they cannot be used for calcultion nor can they be used for proper sorting. Dates saved as text are actually by far the worst you can have in Excel, because neither any human nor the computer can tell you if `12/02/2020` is actually `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` (unless you have any background info about that you have to guess: 50/50 chance). • The **only** correct way I see is parsing the strings and converting them into proper/correct date values **directly when importing**.

Comment: I am aware of all these things. I assumed that all the values are in the same date format i.e. dd/mm/yyyy but excel is changing it to mm/dd/yyyy while copying. So to fix the format i gave this solution. And after copying then we can change text to date format(dd/mm/yyyy)

Answer (score 0):

How ever you "import" your data I absolutely recommend to convert your strings **immediately** into real date values while importing them (right before you write them into a cell). Otherwise you might easily end up in a mess.

Eg Use the `Split()` function to split the strings by their delimiter `/` into day, month and year and then use the `DateSerial(year, month, day)` function

```
Dim RealDate As Date
RealDate = DateSerial(2020, 2, 12)

Range("A1").Value = RealDate
```

to create a real date value, that you then can format to **any** look you like:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

This date is a real date value and can be sorted, and calculated with.

Comment: I am currently copying the entire sheet.



Source_Sheet.Copy After:=Target_Sheet

Comment: @TarriqPillay the question is how do you open/import your CSV? Please show your code or we cannot see how you did it. There are just too many options how one can import CSV data. Edit your original question to include your code.

Comment: Workbooks.Open("filepath") - I think  need to read it as text at this point

Comment: Well, now you show how you copy a worksheet but you didn't show how you import your CSV. Check out [this link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3165-how-to-import-csv-file-into-worksheet.html) and scroll to step 5. In that window you can choose for each column which format it should be, so choose `Date` for you date column and select the correct format that your CSV data has (not what you want it to be later). If you import correcty you can change the date format later using numberformat. But you need to import it correctly first.